# Fetch array with PHP MySQL query

Tags: database, php-5.4, magento1.9.3

So I've had no issues with writing simple queries and pulling the data through that I need (mostly using `fetchOne()`, but this is my first time trying it with a little bit more comprehensive query.

I'm having trouble displaying any of the data that I want, period. This is what I have right now.

```
<?php
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');


$userTable = $resource->getTableName('ced_csmarketplace_vendor_varchar');
$salesTable = $resource->getTableName('ced_csmarketplace_vendor_sales_order');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $userTable.value,
SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total))
FROM $salesTable
INNER JOIN $userTable ON $salesTable.vendor_id=$userTable.entity_id
WHERE payment_state='2'
GROUP BY vendor_id
ORDER BY SUM(base_order_total) DESC
LIMIT 5");
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is fetch the top 5 vendor usernames (`value`), ordered by their total sales amounts. In order to do so, I have to pull from two different tables. I assume I'll have to use a while loop, but am still a little new to fetching data from two different tables in PHP. I know the query works, as I've tested it, it's just a matter of displaying it.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Adding the following code:

```
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

foreach($results as $result)
{
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($result);
}
```

returns this:

```
Array
(
    [value] => User 1
    [SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total))] => 10027.4500
)
Array
(
    [value] => User 2
    [SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total))] => 6796.8500
)
Array
(
    [value] => User 3
    [SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total))] => 6179.2000
)
Array
(
    [value] => User 4
    [SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total))] => 5897.1100
)
Array
(
    [value] => User 5
    [SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total))] => 4178.6100
)
```

So I'm almost there, I just need to get rid of the unnecessary text so that I can then style it myself in the .phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT $userTable.value, SUM(DISTINCT(base_order_total)) FROM $salesTable INNER JOIN $userTable ON $salesTable.vendor_id=$userTable.entity_id WHERE payment_state='2' GROUP BY vendor_id ORDER BY SUM(base_order_total) DESC LIMIT 5":

$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

foreach($results as $result)
{
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($result['value']);
}
```

Comment: This is indeed getting me the entire list now. Thank you. However, it's printing them with text I don't want. I've updated my main post with what it's printing now.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I had needed, I didn't realize it was that simple since I'm still kind of new at fetching from the database myself.

Comment: Play with programming :)